# Modify a recipient to enable requireIDLookup

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the REST API v2.

Consider this scenario:

- Our system creates an envelope with two signers. The second signer
  doesn’t have any kind of authentication via Docusign. In terms of the
  API that means setting signer.requireIdLookup = false (no RSAID verification).
- The first signer signs ok.
- BEFORE the second signer signs the system
  determines that authentication via RSAID is required after all. I
  tried updating signer 2 to enable RSAID, but it doesn’t work. By
  reading the documentation [here](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Modify%20or%20Correct%20and%20Resend%20Recipient%20Information.htm) it looks like changing the
  requireIdLookup on a sent envelope is not supported.

Any ideas on how to do this? Voiding the envelope and starting again is not a good option because we don't want signer 1 to sign again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your workflow.  Are you saying that you create an envelope with two signers with both of them having requireIdLookup = false, but after the first signer signs when the second recipient tries to access the envelope it starts the RSAID flow, even though requireIdLookup was set to false for them?

Comment: Correct. The requirement is simple: How to edit a recipient in a sent envelope to set requiredIdLookup=true

Comment: I think you need to know at the time of envelope creation if you want to requireIDlookup for a recipient or not.  As you've mentioned I don't believe modifying that after the envelope is sent is supported.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this @Ergin. Is there a place to provide user feedback and request new features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comments, this is currently not supported.  You need to determine if you will be using RSA ID check - which is controlled through the requireIDLookup property - at the time you are adding your recipients to the envelope, which might not necessarily be at the time of envelope creation.  It's possible to create the envelope and save it as a draft envelope, then add recipients at a later time.